# 2018 13" MacBook Pro (macOS 10.15.5) kernel panics when uploading binaries via Xcode or Transporter

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina, panic

I am having an issue with my MacBook Pro. Whenever I export an update for my apps via Xcode or Transporter to the App Store, the whole computer freezes and then restarts (kernel panic). I have been experiencing this since 10.15.4 and I thought macOS 10.15.5 update would help but no luck. The computers behaves fine, until I try to upload a binary to the App Store (At least let's say that's the only know way for me to trigger the bug). I did a clean install today, wiping all my data, reinstalling a fresh copy of macOS 10.15.5 and Xcode from the App Store. But  it always occurs after uploading for like 10 minutes. I am disgusted, as a developer, I have to use my wife's 2015 MacBook to upload my binaries, her computer has no issue. Am I the only one ? I would definitely hug that somebody who can help me fix it.

CRASH LOGS:

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f985a1ad5): userspace watchdog timeout: remoted connection watchdog expired, no updates from remoted monitoring thread in 60 seconds, 423 checkins from thread since monitoring enabled 8500 seconds ago after wakeservice: com.apple.logd, total successful checkins since wake (8500 seconds ago): 850, last successful checkin: 10 seconds ago
service: com.apple.WindowServer, total successful checkins since wake (8500 seconds ago): 850, last successful checkin: 10 seconds ago

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff914a6db720 : 0xffffff8017b1f5cd 
0xffffff914a6db770 : 0xffffff8017c58b05 
0xffffff914a6db7b0 : 0xffffff8017c4a68e 
0xffffff914a6db800 : 0xffffff8017ac5a40 
0xffffff914a6db820 : 0xffffff8017b1ec97 
0xffffff914a6db920 : 0xffffff8017b1f087 
0xffffff914a6db970 : 0xffffff80182c2858 
0xffffff914a6db9e0 : 0xffffff7f985a1ad5 
0xffffff914a6db9f0 : 0xffffff7f985a17fa 
0xffffff914a6dba10 : 0xffffff8018254aae 
0xffffff914a6dba60 : 0xffffff7f985a0cfe 
0xffffff914a6dbb60 : 0xffffff801825dcd3 
0xffffff914a6dbca0 : 0xffffff8017c082b2 
0xffffff914a6dbdb0 : 0xffffff8017b25328 
0xffffff914a6dbe10 : 0xffffff8017afbcc5 
0xffffff914a6dbe70 : 0xffffff8017b12aa2 
0xffffff914a6dbf00 : 0xffffff8017c30d05 
0xffffff914a6dbfa0 : 0xffffff8017ac6226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[B435C72B-B311-3C67-8AA1-1D5CE0FAD429]@0xffffff7f985a0000->0xffffff7f985a8fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: watchdogd
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19F96

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Thu Apr 30 18:25:59 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.1~7/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7B7F06EE-1B75-345E-B898-2FD4FEC20F0D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000017800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8017a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8017900000
System model name: MacBookPro15,2 (Mac-827FB448E656EC26)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 25648972761027
last loaded kext at 20989527404840: >usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9bc1f000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 21273759140481: >!UMergeNub   900.4.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9b7a2000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
@nke.rvi    2.0.0
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.6
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.7
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.7
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.428
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.6
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.4
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my 2 months old struggle all came from the fact I had my iPhone connected to the Mac during submissions to App Store. Somebody read my logs on Apple Community and told me:

> usb.cdc.acm appears to be something that interfaces with a USB
>   cellular modems. Since it was the last loaded kext, that might have
>   something to do with it

I unplugged the iPhone during Xcode upload, and it worked fine, so I managed to share my solution with you. Obviously there is a conflict with the iPhone cellular sharing, even though both devices were on Wifi.

Cheers